# When is the image of $\mathbb{R}^n$ a smooth submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be an injective $C^{k}$-function, for some positive integer $k$.  Under what conditions is the complement of the open set (I know its open by Brower's domain invariance theorem) a finite union of smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Where is the integer $k$?

Comment: Ah, it is the smoothness of $f$.

Comment: A  open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is always a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Use for example the trivial chart $\{ \mathrm{id}\}$.

Comment: @DIdier_  You are absolutely correct.  Thought, I unfortuntely made a typo, and am interested rather in the complement of $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a partial answer. Recall that every simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is biholomorphically equivalent to the unit disk $\Delta = \{z\in \mathbb{C}~|~ |z| <1\}$.

Let $\gamma : \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous simple curve that is nowhere differentiable (for example, the Von Koch curve), and let $\Omega$ be its interior (by Jordan's theorem). Then $\Omega$ is a simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ different from $\mathbb{C}$ : there exists a biholomorphism $g : \Delta \to \Omega$. Moreover, $\Delta$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, say $h : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \Delta$ is such a diffeomorphism. Then
\begin{align}
f = g\circ h : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2
\end{align}
is an injective smooth function with image $\Omega$. But $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \Omega$ is not a smooth manifold as otherwise, its boundary would be smooth, that is not the case.

Here has been shown that even if $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$, there is no reason for smoothness to extend to the boundary.

Notice that we could have choosen $\Omega$ to be the interior of a triangle, and the boundary would not be smooth either because of corners. My example shows that it can happen everywhere.

**Edit** It is asked in comment if, whenever $f$ has a dense image, $\mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus \mathrm{Im}(f)$ would be a $n-1$ dimensional smooth manifold. The answer is no. Here is a counter example.

Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{C}$ be an injective curve such that $\gamma$ is nowhere differentiable, and goes to infinity (imagine the trajectory of a brownian motion). Then $ \Omega =\mathbb{C}\setminus\gamma(\mathbb{R}_+)$ is a simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ different from $\mathbb{C}$. The above construction show there is a smooth function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with image $\Omega$, which is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but with complement that is nowhere smooth.

Comment: I'm thinking about your answer, and I wonder.  If $f$ would have dense image in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then wouldn't $\mathbb{R}^n-f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be equal to the boundary of $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  So in this particular case, it would be a smooth manifold of dimension $n-1$?

Or am I erroneously assuming that the boundary of the open set $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ coincidse with its "boundary" as a smooth manifold?

Comment: @Elbebe I edited the answer to show that the answer is negative. In fact, my construction does not use the fact that $\Omega$ is bounded or anything. It just use the fact that $\Omega is open and simply connected, thus you can extand it to your new question. In fact, that is what is surprising in complex analysis: you can say many things about conformal geometry on open subsets, but you can rarely say anything on the boundary!

Comment: @Dldier_ I am abit confused for the following reason.  Since $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is a regular domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of co-dimension 0.  Therefore, by Proposition 5.46 (Lee smooth manifolds) its topological and manifold boundaries coincide.  But isn't the "manifold boundary" of any smooth $n$-manifold itself a smooth manifold of dimension $n-1$?  So why doesn't this imply that $\mathbb{R}^n-f(\mathbb{R}^n)=\partial f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a smooth submanifold?

Comment: Ah, my issue is that $\partial f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is necessarily a $n-1$ dimensional submanifold but not a smooth one.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Elbebe I guess the error is that it is not a properly embedding as the preimage of a compact is not always a compact. For example, $i: \mathbb{R}^* \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not proper as $i^{-1}([0,1]) = (0,1]$ is not compact.

Comment: @Elbebe I've read Lee's proposition. It states that if $M$ is manifold (with boundary) and $D \subset M$ is a subset that is regular (= properly embedded and with codimension $0$), then the topological boundary of $D$ (=$\overline{D}\setminus \overset{\circ}{D}$) is the same as its manifold boundary.
Here, $f(\mathbb{R^n})$ does not have a boundary as a manifold, and is not properly embedded

Comment: I have a follow-up question, for understanding purposes, if you're interested:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3898087/existence-of-proper-self-map-of-euclidean-space-whose-image-has-non-zero-co-dime